# So, where does Grandma work?

Tags: japanese-language, tsuritama

In [episode 1 of Tsuritama](http://www.crunchyroll.com/tsuritama/episode-1-panicked-fishing-595873) Grandma Keito has a new job and she moves to Enoshima with Yuki.  She now works here (time mark 7:11):

[image]

The old-timey font defeats me, and I can't read it.  The best I can do is *Gnolhima Samuel Cocting Garden*. She is obviously a horticulturist of some sort. What is the actual name of the place?  I'm pretty sure "Samuel" and "Garden" are right.

Comment: [Enoshima Samuel Cocking Garden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Cocking_Garden), maybe?

Comment: @Wondercricket I'm sure that's it, thanks! It didn't even occur to me to try looking for a real place. Stupid font. How do you turn a "C" with a flower into an "E", an "l" with a tulip into an "s", and a "t" into a "k"?  Anyway, if your comment were an answer, I would have accepted it.

Comment: I never watched this anime, so I wasn't sure exactly, but I will make it into an answer. The font is definitely interesting; if I can find it, i'll include it into the my answer

Comment: The first word is “Enoshima”; the S is written as [a long S](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s), which appears in older publications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Tsuritama Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsuritama), the store Grandma Keito works at is the
Samuel Cocking Garden

> **Kate (ケイト Keito)**
>
> Yuki's grandmother. She's French, and has a warm
>   and cheerful personality. She allowed Haru to live with her and Yuki.
>   She often gives Haru advice concerning his relationship with Yuki and
>   human social interactions. She works at the [Samuel Cocking Garden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Cocking_Garden) in
>   Enoshima.

This garden, also known as the Enoshima Tropical Plants Garden, is an actual botanical garden in Enoshima, Japan